# How to include a display name when sending mail with mailx

Tags: email, postfix, mailx

I'm sending email from a script using mailx. The script is run daily by systemd, using .service and .timer files. For testing purposes I'm sending from the command line.

The mail is sent with the command

```
echo "Test message - you know the drill" | mailx -r "localweb@example.uk" -s "Test Message" a.user@example.com
```

(personal data replaced for privacy)

This works. It's relayed by postfix to my gateway server (also postfix) which signs the outgoing message. This is then delivered to GMail which verifies the SPF data and DKIM signature, and the message is delivered to my inbox.

This is good, except it's displayed as `Ubuntu <localweb@example.uk>`

I have other servers sending mail by the same method, and they all display similarly.

I'd like to change the display name to something more useful, per server. For example, `Web Server <localweb@example.uk>` but something I'm doing is messing up the `From` address as it travels to the gateway server.

I've tried

```
echo "Test message - you know the drill" | mailx -r "Web Server localweb@example.uk" -s "Test Message" a.user@example.com
```

and

```
echo "Test message - you know the drill" | mailx -r "Web Server <localweb@example.uk>" -s "Test Message" a.user@example.com
```

But in both cases the From address is somehow lost by the local PostFix, and the message sent to the gateway server has a `from` address of `localweb@smtp.private.example.uk` where `smtp.private.example.uk` is the FQDN of the gateway server. This is sent to GMail, but fails the SPF and DKIM tests and is unceremoniously dumped in spam as a result. (I don't know how the local postfix is getting the name of the gateway server)

So, how can I add the display name to the parameters I pass to mailx such that it survives the journey from server to server and is  displayed correctly by GMail?

Mailx version 3.14 (GNU Mailutils)
Ubuntu 22.04

I've made only one change to `main.cf` for PostFix: added a relay-host address for the gateway server.

Comment: Do you have to use `mailx` or are you open to a different tool?

Comment: FWIW, the second method (`-r "Web Server <localweb@example.uk>"`) works for me.

Comment: @StephenHarris Mailx is preferred, just because it's already installed. An easy fix for that would be better. If that's not possible some other tool would be fine. A lightweight SMTP client that talks directly to my gateway server would be ideal.

Comment: @aviro Thanks for the feedback. I thought that method should work. There's definitely something odd going on here. I'll revisit the Postfix config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to use pre-installed programs and because  you have postfix installed, we can use a postfix mode to give you greater control of what you send and how it looks.

This is done via `sendmail -t`.  In this mode we use postfix as a mail submission agent (MSA), which is what `mailx` does anyway, and you can specify the whole header and body, and postfix will send it "as is"

A simple method is to use `echo`.

e.g.

```
echo "From: My name <me@myaddress>
To: You <you@youraddress>
Subject: You'll never guess what...

This is a test!" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

This lets you set any header to any value you like.

Now this doesn't change the *envelope* sender so the original name is visible in other lines, so it's not perfect (but you'd get that with `mailx` if the From address doesn't match the account's address), but it avoids any complications `mailx` or other mail user agents (MUAs) may bring in.

Comment: This resolved the issue with the display name, but has highlighted a problem with the configuration of the source domain. My gateway server is signing correctly for DKIM, but I'm getting some strange responses from the SPF validation. I'll run with it for now, but I'm going to have to come back to this when I have more time. Thanks for your help :)